# Erlang: What does question mark syntax mean?

Tags: syntax, erlang

What does the question mark in Erlang syntax mean?

For example:

```
Json = ?record_to_json(artist, Artist).
```

The full context of the source can be found [here](http://github.com/lambder/jsonerl).

Comment: Used google but didn't come up with anything ( for: "erlang question mark syntax").  Maybe I should activate web history or something to get more relevant results (even using the same keywords results are not the same for everybody especially on more idiosyncratic keywords).  but thanks for comment... still i would appreciate someone with erlang experience providing some more insightful context on how and why used...

Comment: @delnan - Googling brings up this question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Erlang uses question mark to identify [macros](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#id76221). For e.g. consider the below code:

```
-ifdef(debug).
-define(DEBUG(Format, Args), io:format(Format, Args)).
-else.
-define(DEBUG(Format, Args), void).
-endif.
```

As the documentation says,

> Macros are expanded during compilation. A simple macro `?Const` will be replaced with `Replacement`.

This snippet defines a macro called `DEBUG` that is replaced with a call to print a string if `debug` is set at compile time. The macro is then used in the following code thus:

```
?DEBUG("Creating ~p for N = ~p~n", [First, N]),
```

This statement is expanded and replaced with the appropriate contents if `debug` is set. Therefore you get to see debug messages only if `debug` is set.

**Update**

Thanks to [@rvirding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77617/rvirding):

> A question mark means to try and expand what follows as a macro call. There is nothing prohibiting using the macro name (atom or variable) as a normal atom or variable. So in [the above] example you could use `DEBUG` as a normal variable just as long as you don't prefix it with `?`. Confusing, most definitely, but not illegal.

Comment: To be picky: a question mark means to try and expand what follows as a macro call. There is nothing prohibiting using the macro name (atom or variable) as a normal atom or variable. So in your example you could use `DEBUG` as a normal variable just as long as you don't prefix it with `?`. Confusing, most definitely, but not illegal.

Comment: @rvirding: Thanks! Have shamelessly borrowed it and added to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html), I believe it's the syntax for referring to a macro.

And from [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/moduless):

> Erlang macros are really similar to
>   C's '#define' statements, mainly used
>   to define short functions and
>   constants. They are simple expressions
>   represented by text that will be
>   replaced before the code is compiled
>   for the VM. Such macros are mainly
>   useful to avoid having magic values
>   floating around your modules. A macro
>   is defined as a module attribute of
>   the form: -define(MACRO, some_value).
>   and is used as ?MACRO inside any
>   function defined in the module. A
>   'function' macro could be written as
>   -define(sub(X,Y), X-Y). and used like ?sub(23,47), later replaced by 23-47
>   by the compiler. Some people will use
>   more complex macros, but the basic
>   syntax stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

? indicates Macros.

Erlang has predefined macros as well. Example: ?MODULE. You can find the complete list in https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#predefined-macros